# Parametric equation proof

Tags: parametric, rolles-theorem

**Question:**
Suppose $u$ and $v$ are continuous on $[a,b]$ and differentiable on $(a,b)$, and assume that for all $t\in(a,b)$, at least one of $u'(t)$ and $v'(t)$ is nonzero. Let $C$ be the curve given by $(u(t),v(t))$ for $t \in [a,b]$. Let $A = (u(a),v(a))$ and $B = (u(b),v(b))$ be the endpoints of the curve, and assume $A\ne B$. Show that there is some point $c \in (a,b)$ such that the tangent line to $C$ at $(u(c),v(c))$ is parallel to $\overline{AB}$.

**My attempt**

We know the endpoints are:
$$A = (u(a),v(a))$$
$$B = (u(b),v(b))$$
so the gradient of line $AB$ is:
$$\frac{v(a) - v(b)}{u(a) - u(b)}$$

Now the gradient of a point $C$ at point $(u(c),v(c))$ is:
$$\frac{v'(c)}{u'(c)}$$

Now we know Mean Value Theorem as:
$$f'(c) = \frac{f(a) - f(b)}{a-b}$$

Now I don't know how to proceed. I first thought of using MVT for $v(t)$ and $u(t)$ and dividing but the two constant terms need not be equal. So I'm not sure which method to use.

Any help would be much appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $$f(x) = u(x)\Big(v(b)-v(a)\Big)-v(x)\Big(u(b)-u(a)\Big)$$
Then
\begin{align}
f(b) &= v(b)u(a)-u(b)v(a)\\
f(a)&=v(b)u(a)-u(b)v(a)\\
&=f(b)
\end{align}
Therefore, all assumptions of Rolle's theorem are satisfied by f(x) (continuity and differentiablity are obvious). Hence, there is a point $c$ in $[a,b]$ such that $f'(c)=0$. Hence,
\begin{gather}
u'(c)\Big(v(b)-v(a)\Big)-v'(c)\Big(u(b)-u(a)\Big)=0\\
\implies \dfrac{v(b)-v(a)}{u(b)-u(a)} = \dfrac{v'(c)}{u'(c)}
\end{gather}
Hence proved.

Comment: Oh I get it. Thanks a lot!